# How can i output table data (multiple rows) as a multiple rows of concatenated strings

Tags: sql, concatenation, ssms

I am trying to take table data built from a select statement using 2 tables and a group by ... and then output each row of data into a single row concatenated text.

I have tinkered with trying to DECLARE, SET and print as concat string.

```
use ap;

SELECT v.vendorid as 'VendorID', count(i.invoiceid) as 'Invoice Count', 
sum(i.invoicetotal) as 'Invoice Total' 
FROM vendors v
JOIN invoices i on i.vendorid = v.vendorid
GROUP BY v.vendorid
```

trying to output it like...

**VendorID = 34 Invoice Count 2 Invoice Totals = 1,200.12**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just concatenate it into a string. You just need to cast your numeric values to VARCHARs.

```
select 'VendorID = ' + CAST(v.vendorid AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Count ' + CAST(count(i.invoiceid) AS VARCHAR(10)) +
    ' Invoice Totals = ' + FORMAT(sum(i.invoicetotal), 'c2')
from vendors v JOIN invoices i on i.vendorid = v.vendorid 
group by v.vendorid
```

With this sample data:

```
create table vendors (vendorid int)
create table invoices (vendorid int, invoiceid int, invoicetotal money)

insert into vendors values (34)
insert into invoices values (34, 1, 1000), (34, 2, 200.12)
```

Returns:

```
VendorID = 34 Count 2 Invoice Totals = $1,200.12
```

Comment: That worked perfectly ... I was overthinking it for sure. thanks so much.